# Grunt slow on network

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I've created a grunt file on a project I'm working on. We have a template and that is used across a range of products but it's all saved to our network. When I run `grunt default` on the template it completes it in seconds. When I move the template to one of the project folders running `grunt default` again (or `grunt watch`) will take ~20 minutes to complete.

These files are stored on the same drive with pathways a little something like this: (I've changed the names slightly):

- /Volumes/Company/shared/Code Library/HTML/Template
- /Volumes/Company/Project/assets/unit/development/source

Does anyone know why it would take so long for a grunt task to complete in one folder but not the other? If I copy it to the desktop it also completes a `watch` or `default` task in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Upon further investigation into this all of our project folder names have a "code" on the end, e.g. (LO), (WS), (TG) and so on. That addition is causing the issues with Grunt. Can't change our folder name structure but I at least know why it's happening now.